# JSON: Jackson stream parser - is it really worth it?

Tags: android, json, jackson

I'm making pretty heavy use of JSON parsing in an app I'm writing.  Most of what I have done is already implemented using Android's built in JSONObject library (is it json-lib?).

JSONObject appears to create instances of absolutely everything in the JSON string... even if I don't end up using all of them.

My app currently runs pretty well, even on a G1.

My question is this: are the speed and memory benefits from using a stream parser like Jackson worth all the trouble?

By trouble, I mean this:  As far as I can tell, there are three downsides to using Jackson instead of the built in library:

1. Dependency on an external library.  This makes your .apk bigger in the end.  Not a huge deal.
2. Your app is more fragile.  Since the parsing is not done automatically, it is more vulnerable to changes in the JSON text that it's parsing (perhaps I'm wrong about this).
3. Writing code to parse JSON via a stream parser is ugly and tedious.

Comment: I don't agree with #2.  If the JSON structure changes in an unexpected way, you're really out of luck regardless.

Comment: Not true in certain cases.. for instance, adding an object as a value in another object.  Unless you plan for it in the pull parser, it'll throw it off, while with JSONObject, it'll just work.

For example:  Changing 

{
  "first_name": "Adam", 
  "last_name": "Olsen"
} 

to 
{
  "first_name": "Adam, 
  "last_name: "Olsen", 
  "phone_numbers": {
    "home": "555-867-5309", 
    "work": "888-555-5555"
   }
}

Would throw your pull parser off in a loop like: while(parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT)

 - You'd end up hitting END_OBJECT early, where JSONObject would parse it fine.

Comment: It is possible to write a stream parser that copes with that.  I believe this is what shipChildren (http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.5.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParser.html#skipChildren%28%29) is for.

Comment: Unless you are having performance issues, it doesn't matter what the API is doing under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess you've pretty much answered your own question. :)
Using the built-in JSON parser myself and have never looked for an alternative.

EDIT: Now I'm using a thin annotation-based wrapper from [DroidParts](http://droidparts.org).

Answer (score 6):

I am also using the build-in JSON parser in most cases, but recently stepped into a scenario where it doesn't fit: For some web service requests I receive JSON documents of more than 1 MB. Loading these with the build-in JSON parser requires tremendous amounts of main memory and resulted in `OutOfMemoryException` several times. For these scenarios a streaming parser is the better choice (even though it is more inconvenient in use) and the built-in JSON parser does not provide streaming, but only the DOM-like style.

For anyone looking for a streaming JSON parser for Android I can strongly recommend to use [Google's GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). I've tried Jackson JSON at first and it worked fine until I tried to build the release version of my app: ProGuard reported several issues and the running app crashed with mysterious `NullPointerException` in the constructor of Jackson's `ObjectMapper` (though everything worked fine in the debug version). Even after a few hours of trying around I wasn't able to fix this. I then switched to GSON then and everything worked like a charm.

BTW: The GSON streaming-only jar has a size of only 14kB -- so nothing to really worry about.

Comment: Turns out that there is a way to make ProGuard content; my co-worker figured it out. I hope to convince him to blog about details, as it's unfortunately not a one-liner. Fundamentally ProGuard's weakness is that it relies on static analysis, which runs into trouble with reflection. One thing to note is that if only using Jackson's streaming stuff (JsonParser, JsonGenerator) from core jar, there shouldn't be issues. It's mapper part that uses reflection heavily.

Comment: Would you mind pointing those of use that has run into the NullPointerException issue into the general direction of the solution if we must use the mapper?

Comment: As mentioned in my post I haven't found a solution for the `NullPointerException`. That's why I've switchted to GSON.

Comment: StaxMan mentioned that his co-worker figured it out, though it appears not to be a simple solution.

Comment: Sorry, haven't read the comments correctly...

Comment: @StaxMan: I only wanted to use the streaming stuff, but unfortunately I were not able to do so. Creating the `JsonParser` as shown in the tutorial didn't work for me as it crashed with a `NullPointerException`. I needed to call `setCodec(new ObjectMapper())` to make this work and so I needed more than just the streaming API.

Comment: Right, but if you are using codec, you are not using just streaming stuff but the full mapper. So this is not pro-guard bug (or bug in general; although error reporting should be improved to indicate issue). Basic streaming API does not use Codec (i.e. ObjectMapper) for anything; 'readValueAs()' is just a convenience accessor which works same as if you called ObjectMapper.readValue(JsonParser, type) directly. I hope this helps.

Comment: This might be veeeery late but I just saw this and decided to add my two cents. The only jackson related bit I have in my proguard configuration is this: `-keepclasseswithmembers public class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper {
    public java.lang.String writeValueAsString(java.lang.Object);
    }`

Answer (score 2):

I think question is whether built-in one is good enough. If it is, sure, minimizing dependencies is often a good strategy. Good enough can refer to both efficiency and ease of use.

For what it's worth, Jackson also has a decent tree model as well as full data binding.
Tree model is significantly faster than default parser (parsing is 3x-5x faster on J2SE, probably similarly on other platforms like Android, tree model itself is probably more efficient as well).
Or: if you don't want dependency to second jar (mapper is needed for tree model and data binding), writing your own tree to cover your use cases is simple too. Either use basic HashMap/ArrayList/wrappers, or have your own classes if you prefer. Builder would be maybe 40 lines of code top.